# convert pdf to byteArray - byteArray to String - String to byteArray - byteArray to pdf

Tags: java, arrays, pdf

I have the following code which works for text files but doesn't work for `pdf` files. My files contain english and greek characters. I try to convert a `pdf` file to `byteStream` and the `byteStream` to `String` format in order to save it in `database`. After this I try to create the `pdf` from the saved String.

Any help?

```
public class PdfToByteStream {

    public static byte[] convertDocToByteArray(String path)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File file = new File(path);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(genJpeg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    }

    public static void convertByteArrayToDoc(String path, byte[] bytes)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File someFile = new File(path);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        byte[] bytes = convertDocToByteArray("path/test.pdf");

        String stream = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");//ok for txt
        byte[] newBytes = stream.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // ok for txt

        convertByteArrayToDoc("path/newTest.pdf", newBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences

Comment: Write on the blackboard 100 times after school: '`String` is not a container for binary data.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding you will be able to convert the PDF to a string and back.

Here is the relevant part of the code which needs to be changed:

```
import java.util.Base64;

...

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    byte[] bytes = convertDocToByteArray("some.pdf");
    String stream = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    byte[] newBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stream);
    convertByteArrayToDoc("some_new.pdf", newBytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my time!